# Are bootstrap dashboard themes easilly interchangable (compatible)?

Tags: theme, bootstrap

I'd like to start developing a dashboard using bootstrap.
For now I'm not concerned about design, so I'd like to just pick a theme randomly and start developing. However I'm concerned about locking myself into the chosen design.

Would it be possible to let end-users choose between different themes when the app is live. How dynamically can themes be switched using bootstrap?

Will I need to make an extra abstraction layer between the gauges and charts or do these UI elements in different themes have the same interface?

Comment: Please remove your unrelated question.    You may ask your unrelated question only in a separate post.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I rephrased the 2nd part of the question and made it a little more specific by adding an example (chart and gauge interfaces). Thanks for leaving a comment instead of just voting to close without giving any clue why.

Answer (score 2):

Not seamlessly interchangeable.

*You need some basic HTML and CSS knowledge in order to be able to switch different themes.*

However, if you make sure your different themes are using the same Bootstrap version (v2.0 - old, v3.0 - most used, v4.0 - beta) and you are familiar with HTML you should be able to switch them.

I used to work with the official Bootstrap themes (they used to be free), more recently I have been using [startboostrap.com](https://startbootstrap.com/template-categories/all/) (nb - I am in no way affiliated with them), which by the way have a [basic dashboard template](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin/).

Comment: Thanks @ionesuc77, so that kind of rules out dynamically switching or letting customers choose (or purchase their own). and this kind of forces me to make a theme choice up front...

Comment: You need some basic web development skills to switch themes on the fly. Colours I guess it is more simple. But for a theme, you would need to refresh/reload the page and assets (css files). So you would need to go into javascript programing. It is doable, but definitelly some work will be needed.

Comment: Ok, switching themes would be a full page reload anyway. Then it depends on how assets are loaded dynamically. If I can point to them in the page, I could prefex all files with the theme's directory, but if they are loaded dynamically from javascript it would be a pain (especially if some paths must be the same since browsers would cache stuff). After looking closer at some themes it looks like most of them are more like extensions instead of a simple skin. It doesn't look like charts are using a common interface either :-(